# Which cylinder door lock shield design is most secure?

Tags: doors, lock, security

I'm planning to place a shield on my front door and would like to know which of the 3 shield designs is the most secure option and why.

Basic design characteristics:

Top Left:

- the outside part of the cylinder is covered with a black steel covering

Bottom:

- the outside part of the cylinder is covered with a black steel covering
- it has another fastening screw on the top part

Top Right:

- the cylinder is completely "invisible" (covered) from the outside

[image: euro cylinder shields]

Comment: Just a comment: If someone approaches a lock with a drill capable of drilling through it and has the intent of doing so, I highly doubt they'd be deterred by a hardened lock cover and simply give up. There is always a 'weakest point' in your security, and at best upgrading to a lock like this will simply shift your lock a tiny bit further away from being the weakest point. If it IS the weakest point, that probably means your house has no windows, re-enforced concrete walls and the door can withstand a battering ram. Sounds lovely.

Comment: I see a screws on all of the plates that presumably would be easy to unscrew and then push the lock cylinder side out of the door. ?? Are the doors designed to keep people out from the plate side or the cylinder side ?

Answer (score 3):

Effectively there should be no difference.  They only vary for aesthetic purposes.  Someone trying to access the door via cutting the cylinder would have to work very hard indeed regardless of which model you pick.

What's much more important is that you ensure that the rest of the door is as secure as the lock mechanism itself.

Comment: I've just realized that the Top-Right is probably the most secure because since it is 100% covered, it is also anti-drill, unlike the other two.

Comment: If I'm drilling a lock, I'm not coming in from the side...

Comment: Door and casement are the weak spots, nobody's going to bother drilling a lock if they want in, even in the country where they'll be undisturbed. There are a lot softer spots for entry than the door. An alarm system with glass breakage detectors is actually more safe than any door lock you can buy. Defense in depth if you're really concerned.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - Yep, Drill bit down through the keyhole, self-tapping bolt and a slide-hammer puller is the usual means. Guts the cylinder right out of the housing and gives you direct access to the internals. Less noisy methods are used IRL for nefarious activity.